# Every cycle is a composition of simple cycles

Tags: graph-theory

In a directed multigraph:

Every cycle (closed walk) is a composition of simple cycles, right?

Moreover, every finite path is a composition of simple paths, right?

What is the simplest proof of this?

Comment: By induction? $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about undirected closed walks, it is not the case that every closed walk is a composition of simple cycles. For example consider $P_3$ with any orientation and $V(P_3)=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ labelled in the canonical way. Then $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_2,v_1)$ is a closed walk, but $P_3$ is acyclic so there is no way this could be a composition of cycles.

For a directed closed walk, it suffices to show that the graph induced by the arcs of the walk is an Eulerian digraph, and all Eulerian digraphs can be decomposed into arc-disjoint directed cycles(this can be proven by induction.)

As for open walks(directed or undirected) being a composition of paths, just do induction on the length of the walk as a comment suggested. A walk of length zero is just $P_1$. Then in the induction, you can always express a walk of length $k(>0)$ as a walk of length $k-1$ and a walk of length $1$. It follows immediately from that.